# Order Export Error after adding new columns in the order grid through Renderer

Tags: magento

FYI, I have added 2 custom columns in Sales > Order Grid by using the code below in grid.php file.

```
$this->addColumn(’ddmsaccount’,array(
‘header’ => Mage::helper(’customer’)->__(’DDMS Account #’),
‘width’ => ‘50’,
‘renderer’ => ‘Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Ddms’,
‘filter’ => false,
‘sortable’ => false,
‘index’ => ‘ddmsaccount’
));
```

Everything is working fine: custom columns are seen in the Grid layout, Filtering/ Rendering all works fine.

The only issue that i am getting is that the custom columns are not exported in the CSV.

Let me know if anyone has any idea on this.
Thanks
Pawan